# help tweaking regular expression in perl

Tags: regex, perl

Can someone help me tweak this regex? It's grabbing `72.49 GB` and I'm ONLY interested in the value `72.49`

```
$line =~ m/(backup-size)[:=](.+)/
```

Raw String:

```
Tue Jan 04 05:45:34 2011: db2.mil.mad:backup:INFO: backup-size=72.49 GB
```

Comment: That last `)` isn't part of the regex, is it?

Comment: sorry, no its not. i removed it. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$line =~ m/backup-size[:=](\d+\.?\d*)\s*[KMG]B/i;
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
$line =~ m/backup-size[:=]([\d.]+) GB/;
```

To select both the size and the unit in separate groups:

```
$line =~ m/backup-size[:=]([\d.]+) (.B)/;
```

Comment: That breaks if the backup size is in MBs :)

Comment: @DVK: Yeah it's "broken" (depending on what he is using it for)... however that's actually what he was *asking* for (see his question). However, I have now provided a "fixed" version that I believe also answers his question without being "broken". (PS: Check out the answer he accepted - if you think mine is "broken" don't you think that's even *more* "broken" than my original answer?? It will give him meaningless numbers instead of meaningful numbers but only some of the time.)